# Python - Using a created list as a parameter

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, compare

When I run my code it tells me: Type Error: unorderable types: str() < float(). I can't figure out why it won't let me compare these two numbers. The list I am using is defined, and the numbers in it have been redefined as floats, so I'm not sure what else to do. Any suggestions?

```
    def countGasGuzzlers(list1, list2):   
        total = 0
        CCount = 0
        HCount = 0
        for line in list1:
            if num < 22.0:
                total = total + 1
                CCount = CCount + 1
        for line in list2:
            if num < 27.0:
                total = total + 1
                Hcount = Hcount = 1
        print('City Gas Guzzlers: ',CCount)
        print('Highway Gas Guzzlers: ',HCount)
        print('Total Gas Guzzlers: ',total)
```

This is my list definition. I'm pretty sure it's fine, but maybe there are some bugs in here as well?

```
     CityFile = open('F://SSC/Spring 2015/CSC 110/PythonCode/Chapter 8/HW 4/carModelData_city','r')
    for line in CityFile:
            CityData = CityFile.readlines()
            for num in CityData:
                numCityData = float(num)
                CityList = numCityData
    HwyFile = open('F://SSC/Spring 2015/CSC 110/PythonCode/Chapter 8/HW 4/carModelData_hwy','r')
    for line in HwyFile:
            HwyData = HwyFile.readlines()
            for num in HwyData:
                    numHwyData = float(num)
                    HwyList = numHwyData
```

Comment: what is `num` and where is it defined

Comment: It isn't defined. I am trying to compare the numbers in my list to the 22 or 27.

Comment: So you should be assigning the *numbers in my list* to `num` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are incorrectly referencing to `num` instead of `line` which is the counter variable in your `for` loops, you either need to use `num` as the counter variable, or use `line` in the `if` condition.

```
def countGasGuzzlers(list1, list2):   
    total = 0
    CCount = 0
    HCount = 0
    for line in list1:
        if float(line) < 22.0:
            total = total + 1
            CCount = CCount + 1
    for line in list2:
        if float(line) < 27.0:
            total = total + 1
            Hcount = Hcount = 1
    print('City Gas Guzzlers: ',CCount)
    print('Highway Gas Guzzlers: ',HCount)
    print('Total Gas Guzzlers: ',total)
```

---

Another issue I see is with the way you are creating the lists . The issue is that you are converting each num in file to float and then storing that directly in list variable, which causes list variable to actually store a float value instead of a list, you need to append each value into list, instead of doing `list = num`

The code would look like -

```
CityFile = open('F://SSC/Spring 2015/CSC 110/PythonCode/Chapter 8/HW 4/carModelData_city','r')
for line in CityFile:
        CityData = CityFile.readlines()
        for num in CityData:
            numCityData = float(num)
            CityList.append(numCityData)
HwyFile = open('F://SSC/Spring 2015/CSC 110/PythonCode/Chapter 8/HW 4/carModelData_hwy','r')
for line in HwyFile:
        HwyData = HwyFile.readlines()
        for num in HwyData:
                numHwyData = float(num)
                HwyList.append(numHwyData)
```

Please also make sure CityList and HwyList are initialized before this code as lists. Like below -

```
CityList = []
HwyList = []
```

Comment: I have tried using line instead of num and it still does not work. It gives the same error.

Comment: Can you print out the list1 and list2 and show us here?

Comment: Just updated the answer, you can use `float(line)` incase the lists contain strings instead of float

Comment: says it isn't iterable.

Comment: Please edit the complete code in the question, I see an issue with the code where you are creating the lists.

Comment: Where do you see the issue?

Comment: Tells me `CityList` and `HwyList` aren't defined when I run it.

Comment: Updated the answer, i guessed you would face that :) . Anyway I would highly recommend taking some kind of online course in python

Comment: Thank you! And actually, I just did. Super beginner class, and obviously I'm not that great. haha. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would advice you accept answers, and upvote if apropriate, would keep the community motivated.